# Linq without "into" word reserved in vb.net

Tags: linq

i am using vb.net and linq to sql (.dbml) yet... And i need create a "left join". I could see in msdn site that one way is using "into" as showed in code/link below

Site reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

But i tried to implement this code and "into" isn't a reserved word, the compile doesn't know it.

what am i doing wrong? Linq's version?

Thanks!

Comment: You've linked to a page which only contains a C# example as far as I can tell - you shouldn't expect that to work as VB.

Comment: Yes, you right, the convert is different but the problem was the "into" reserved word wasn't been recognized. I find the issue, the "Into" word needs to be in the next line and into a group for example in this page, its right now eheheh. site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx on method: Sub LeftOuterJoinExample()

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the VB equivalent, which is probably "Into" instead of "into" : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737909